# python gdata "too many redirects from server: 302"

Tags: python, redirect, google-calendar-api, gdata-api, http-status-code-302

I have this code...

```
while (True):

    try:
        feed_entry = cal_client.GetCalendarEventFeed(process_steps_dev_cal_link).entry
        feed_entry2 = cal_client.GetCalendarEventFeed(backup_steps_dev_cal_link).entry
        break
    except gdata.client.RedirectError, e:
        print e
```

I am grabbing two calendar links from my cal_client login.
However, the RedirectError keeps showing up like this...

```
Too many redirects from server: 302, <HTML>
<HEAD>
<TITLE>Moved Temporarily</TITLE>
</HEAD>
<BODY BGCOLOR="#FFFFFF" TEXT="#000000">
<H1>Moved Temporarily</H1>
The document has moved <A HREF="https://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/"myemail"/private/full?gsessionid=2jV2trFEab1MHFHbjnGU4Q">here</A>.
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

What is the cause of this? Everything was working fine until today. Also, it doesn't do this every time. Sometimes it works, sometimes it doesn't. But mostly not.

Answer (score 0):

There's something wrong here:

```
<A HREF="https://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/"myemail"/private/full?gsessionid=2jV2trFEab1MHFHbjnGU4Q">
```

The link itself has an HREF that points to `https://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/` because `"myemail"` is part of the link, and that's probably causing a redirect. Check the links that you are passing to `cal_client.GetCalendarEventFeed()` and make sure they are properly formed.